# DPDK distributor issues - not giving workers packets

Tags: amazon-web-services, fpga, dpdk

I have something working that is modified from the DPDK distributor example.

The distributor ( d ) is set up on a core and receives mbufs which are passed through a loop with the funtions:

```
rte_distributor_process(d, mbufs, nb_rx);
rte_distributor_returned_pkts(d, mbufs, 4*BURST_SIZE);
```

The workers just call:

```
num = rte_distributor_get_pkt(d, id, mbuf, mbuf, num);
```

With the monitoring core running ( from the example ) it shows that if i pass in different id's to different cores, only one worker is given jobs ( even if this worker cant keep up ). If i set the id of them to be all the same ( not safe i know ), then they will be distributed to each worker properly like so:

```
num = rte_distributor_get_pkt(d, 0, mbuf, mbuf, num);
```

Basically, the *rte_distributor_get_pkt* function is blocking for all other ids after one id gets a packet.

There must be something in the setup I am not doing correctly. Any ideas?

I am running this on an AWS F1 Instance with amazons version of DPDK, a branch from v18.05 it appears. From the diff it only looks like they added a driver for the FPGA.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No sorry, i hacked my way around to only needing one worker